# the entity returned from the jsf page is persisted with a null value

Tags: java, jsf-2

In my application when i click the add button and after i enter the values and try to save the object in the database its been persisted as a null value with no error message in the log file.The primary key is generated from a sequence i am just entering the name value. Here is the code of the jsf page

```
                  <p:inputText id="newnom" value="#{groupeBean.nomValue}"
                        required="true" validatorMessage="Le nom est obligatoire">
                        <f:validateRequired />
                        <p:ajax event="blur" update="newnom_msg"></p:ajax>
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="newnom_msg" for="newnom" />
                    <p:separator />
                    <h:outputText value="Tous les Champs sont Obligatoire"
                        class="font-custom" style="font-size:9pt"></h:outputText>
                    <br />
                    <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer" update="growl"
                        actionListener="#{groupeBean.create}"
                        oncomplete="GroupeCree.hide()"></p:commandButton>
```

and this is the code of the managed bean

```
                      private Groupe newGroupe=new Groupe();
                      private List<SelectItem> grpsItem;
                       private DataModel groupes;
                       private Groupe editGroupe;
                      private String nomValue;
                      private DaoGroupe gdao= new DaoGroupe();

                      public String getNomValue() {
                 System.out.println("  gnom "+nomValue);
                 return nomValue;
                         }
             public void setNomValue(String nom) {
            System.out.println("  gNOM "+nom);
            this.nomValue = nom;
                   }
                 public String create()
                   {
System.out.println("  creategnom "+nomValue);
newGroupe.setNom(nomValue);
gdao.ajouter(newGroupe);
newGroupe=new Groupe();
groupes.setWrappedData(gdao.selectAll());
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Ajout effectué avec succés");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
        return "list";

                   }
                  public Groupe getNewGroupe() {
               System.out.println("  NEWgrp "+newGroupe.getNom());
                   return newGroupe;}
               public void setNewGroupe(Groupe newGroupe) {
                 this.newGroupe = newGroupe;
                System.out.println("  NEWgrp "+newGroupe.getNom());
                 }
```

I  am not using EJB as i am a beginner i am using a dao class and here is its code

```
                    public class DaoGroupe {
                private static final String JPA_UNIT_NAME="Portail";
                 private EntityManager entityManager=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
        JPA_UNIT_NAME).createEntityManager();;
               protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            if (entityManager == null) {
        entityManager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
                JPA_UNIT_NAME).createEntityManager();
                              }
               return entityManager;
                       }

                  public   void ajouter(Groupe g)
              {
        EntityTransaction tx = getEntityManager().getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        entityManager.persist(g);
        tx.commit();

              }
```

i can't figure out what's wrong there's no error message and i don't know what's the mistake 
this is the stack trace after doing what Adarsh told me to do

```
                         2014-01-03T23:06:33.136+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                          2014-01-03T23:06:33.583+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.711+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.786+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.787+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.788+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.789+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.790+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.791+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.792+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.793+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.794+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.795+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.795+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.796+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.797+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.798+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.799+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.800+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.801+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.802+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.803+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.803+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.804+0100|Infos: visiting unvisited references
                  2014-01-03T23:06:33.920+0100|Infos: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for                    EJB AuthentificationEjb:   [java:global/Portail/AuthentificationEjb!com.portail.beans.AuthentificationEjb, java:global/Portail/AuthentificationEjb]
                 2014-01-03T23:06:35.953+0100|Infos: Registering the Jersey servlet application, named org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.rs.service.JPARSApplication, at the servlet mapping /persistence/*, with the Application class of the same name.
                 2014-01-03T23:06:35.957+0100|Infos: Initialisation de Mojarra 2.2.0 ( 20130502-2118 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.0@11930) pour le contexte «/Portail»
                  2014-01-03T23:06:36.099+0100|Avertissement: WELD-001529 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for a class org.primefaces.context.PrimeFacesContextFactory which does not have any appropriate constructor.
                 2014-01-03T23:06:36.107+0100|Avertissement: WELD-001529 An InjectionTarget implementation is created for a class org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContextFactory which does not have any appropriate constructor.
                 2014-01-03T23:06:36.427+0100|Avertissement: JSF1057 : La ressource référencée par from-view-id, «index.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée. 
                 2014-01-03T23:06:36.427+0100|Avertissement: JSF1058 : La ressource référencée par to-view-id, «loginfailed.xhtml», pour la navigation depuis «/index.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée.
                2014-01-03T23:06:36.428+0100|Avertissement: JSF1057 : La ressource référencée par from-view-id, «loginfailed.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée. 
                2014-01-03T23:06:36.428+0100|Avertissement: JSF1058 : La ressource référencée par to-view-id, «loginfailed.xhtml», pour la navigation depuis «/loginfailed.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée.
                     2014-01-03T23:06:36.428+0100|Avertissement: JSF1057 : La ressource référencée par from-view-id, «loginfailed.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée. 
                    2014-01-03T23:06:36.429+0100|Avertissement: JSF1058 : La ressource référencée par to-view-id, «forum.xhtml», pour la navigation depuis «/loginfailed.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée.
                    2014-01-03T23:06:36.429+0100|Avertissement: JSF1057 : La ressource référencée par from-view-id, «loginfailed.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée. 
                    2014-01-03T23:06:36.429+0100|Avertissement: JSF1058 : La ressource référencée par to-view-id, «forum.xhtml», pour la navigation depuis «/loginfailed.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée.
                           2014-01-03T23:06:36.430+0100|Avertissement: JSF1057 : La ressource référencée par from-view-id, «index.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée. 
                      2014-01-03T23:06:36.430+0100|Avertissement: JSF1058 : La ressource référencée par to-view-id, «forum.xhtml», pour la navigation depuis «/index.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée.
                       2014-01-03T23:06:36.430+0100|Avertissement: JSF1057 : La ressource référencée par from-view-id, «index.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée. 
                           2014-01-03T23:06:36.430+0100|Avertissement: JSF1058 : La ressource référencée par to-view-id, «forum.xhtml», pour la navigation depuis «/index.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée.
                           2014-01-03T23:06:36.431+0100|Avertissement: JSF1057 : La ressource référencée par from-view-id, «indexAdmin.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée. 
                        2014-01-03T23:06:36.431+0100|Avertissement: JSF1058 : La ressource référencée par to-view-id, «administrateur.xhtml», pour la navigation depuis «/indexAdmin.xhtml», ne commence pas par ’’/’’.  Ce caractère sera ajouté pour vous, mais l’erreur doit être corrigée.
                       2014-01-03T23:06:36.847+0100|Infos: Running on PrimeFaces 4.0
                      2014-01-03T23:06:36.866+0100|Infos: Loading application [Portail] at [/Portail]
                     2014-01-03T23:06:37.021+0100|Infos: Portail was successfully deployed in 5 701 milliseconds.
                      2014-01-03T23:06:38.198+0100|Infos: gnom null
                      2014-01-03T23:06:47.946+0100|Infos: creategnom null
                       2014-01-03T23:06:47.947+0100|Avertissement:                        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.portail.entities.Groupe@24b1fc1d is not a known entity type.
                       javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.portail.entities.Groupe@24b1fc1d is not a known entity type.
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:818)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
                    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.portail.entities.Groupe@24b1fc1d is not a known entity type.
at  org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4222)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
at com.portail.dao.DaoGroupe.ajouter(DaoGroupe.java:27)
at com.portail.managedBeans.GroupeBean.create(GroupeBean.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275)
... 41 more
```

this is the Groupe class code

```
                     @Entity
                 @NamedQuery(name = "Groupe.findAll", query = "SELECT g FROM Groupe g")
            public class Groupe implements Serializable {
           private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    @SequenceGenerator(name = "grp_seq", sequenceName = "SEQ_PK_GRP", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
                 @Id
                @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "grp_seq")
                @Column(name = "ID_GROUPE")
               private long idGroupe;
               @Column(length = 20, unique = true)
               private String nom;
              // bi-directional many-to-one association to Etudiant
             @OneToMany(mappedBy = "groupe", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
              private List<Etudiant> etudiants;

// bi-directional many-to-many association to Professeur
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "groupes", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Professeur> professeurs;

public Groupe() {
}

public long getIdGroupe() {
    return this.idGroupe;
}

public void setIdGroupe(long idGroupe) {
    this.idGroupe = idGroupe;
}

public String getNom() {
    return this.nom;
}

public void setNom(String nom) {
    this.nom = nom;
}

public List<Etudiant> getEtudiants() {
    return this.etudiants;
}

public void setEtudiants(List<Etudiant> etudiants) {
    this.etudiants = etudiants;
}

public Etudiant addEtudiant(Etudiant etudiant) {
    getEtudiants().add(etudiant);
    etudiant.setGroupe(this);

    return etudiant;
}

public Etudiant removeEtudiant(Etudiant etudiant) {
    getEtudiants().remove(etudiant);
    etudiant.setGroupe(null);

    return etudiant;
}

public List<Professeur> getProfesseurs() {
    return this.professeurs;
}

public void setProfesseurs(List<Professeur> professeurs) {
    this.professeurs = professeurs;
}
```

My RDBMS is Oracle10g xe

Comment: Have you tried printing the value in the getter and setters ?

Comment: In your bean you would have a getGroupe method, try printing the value of one of the properties of Groupe class.

Comment: Just write a system.out.println in your method and print the value of Groupe.nom. When you execute your page, it will print the correct value.

Comment: Groupe.nom return null

Comment: In both getNewGroupe and setNewGroupe ?

Comment: yes both of them return null

Comment: Try defining a new String attribute in the bean, use that string to store the value you input in the inputText. Then in your create method which is invoked when you press the commandbutton, assign the value of the new String to newGroupe.nom and then try persisting it. Also, check the value in the getter and setter of the new String used.

Comment: i tried so and now i am getting this exception `Avertissement: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.portail.entities.Groupe@50bd45e1 is not a known entity type.
javax.el.ELException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: com.portail.entities.Groupe@50bd45e1 is not a known entity type.`

Comment: What is the EL that you have used ?

Comment: i used this EL #{groupeBean.nom} after creating nom and its getters and setters in groupeBean

Comment: Have you set the nom value to the concerned object on button click ?

Comment: yes `public String create()
{
 newGroupe.setNom(nom);
 gdao.ajouter(newGroupe);
 groupes.setWrappedData(gdao.selectAll());
 newGroupe=new Groupe();
 FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Ajout effectué avec succés");
 FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
   return "list";
 
}`

Comment: Have you mapped the class GroupE to the correct table and used all the right annotations ?

Comment: yes i think so and this is a part of my Groupe entity `@SequenceGenerator(name = "grp_seq", sequenceName = "SEQ_PK_GRP", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "grp_seq")
 @Column(name = "ID_GROUPE")
 private long idGroupe;
 @Column(length = 20, unique = true)
 private String nom;`

Comment: Post the part of the code which is throwing the exception. The stack trace must have that information.a

Comment: Today the exception dispeared but the attribute Nom i created to assign to the Groupe instance is returning null

Comment: In the setter method, it should print the value you are entering when the page is submitted.

Comment: yes the value submitted is a null string

Comment: Then there is something wrong with the code .

Comment: i know that there is something messing or something i did wrong but i don't know where i already posted the code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem : For anyone having an error like this , You should make sure that `@ManagedBean` and the scope annotation are imported from `javax.faces.bean.*` otherwise the mangedBen won't be able to get the values from the JSF page.

You need also to make sure that you input fields are inside a form element .
For more details refer to this [ManagedBean Params not accepted and Bean seemingly not in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21082219/managedbean-params-not-accepted-and-bean-seemingly-not-in-scope/21082533#21082533)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSF should contain the following

```
 <p:inputText id="newnom" value="#{groupeBean.nomValue}"
                    required="true" validatorMessage="Le nom est obligatoire">
                    <f:validateRequired />
                    <p:ajax event="blur" update="newnom_msg"></p:ajax>
                </p:inputText>
 <p:commandButton value="Enregistrer" update="growl"
                    actionListener="#{groupeBean.create}"
                    oncomplete="GroupeCree.hide()"></p:commandButton>
```

The managed Bean should be as follows.

```
@ManagedBean(name="groupeBean")
```

with method

```
public String create(){
           gdao.ajouter(newGroupe);
            newGroupe=new Groupe();
            groupes.setWrappedData(gdao.selectAll());
                FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Ajout effectué avec succés");
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); 
    return "list";
}
```

and with a new property

```
String nomValue; (with its getter and setter).
```

Put Sysouts in the create() method and also the getter and setter and provide me the output after the following;

1. page load
2. after you input a value in the input box.
3. after you press the commandButton.

Comment: I did as you said and i posted the changed code in the question but te remarkable thing is that it only prints the sysouts of the nomValue getter and the create method but it dosen't print the sysout of the newGroupe getter nor setter and also after i enter the value in the dialog my datable containg the Groupe value in the jsf page is not update and the facesMessage dosen't appear

Comment: But the values are all null ? even after you enter a value on the page and submit it ?

Comment: Post your Groupe class too

Comment: i have fixed the exception but the values are still null as the stack 
`file:/C:/glassfish4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/Portail/WEB-INF/classes/_Portail login successful
2014-01-04T00:25:21.703+0100|Infos: NEWgrp null
2014-01-04T00:25:31.518+0100|Infos: creategnom null
2014-01-04T00:25:38.546+0100|Infos: NEWgrp null`