# ManagedBean Params not accepted and Bean seemingly not in scope

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

This uses the same code that comes from 
[primefaces tree control](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/treeEvents.jsf)

```
@ManagedBean( name = "theName", eager = true)
```

The first question is why "name" and "eager" are not recognised. Eclipse suggests I change either parameter to "value" - so not sure whats going on there.

Then, where I have been careful to capitalise where necessary and create my bean

```
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {
```

and reference it in my xhtml

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
```

```
<p:tree id="treeSingle" value="#{treeBean.root}" var="node"
        selectionMode="single"
        selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}">
```

(paying attention to the capitalisation of the classname).

The output shows only a narrow bar. System.out.println("Constructor called") suggests the bean is not known. To support this, if I press the button as coded in the example (link provided at the top) I get the error

```
Jan 13, 2014 12:19:26 AM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /HelloWorld.xhtml @23,50 selection="#{treeBean.selectedNode}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'treeBean' resolved to null
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:133)
```

I've run out of ideas now as to what could be the problem. Is there any way of further debugging this or anyone got any ideas about the eager/name thing and what is causing the Bean class to be (I assume) not to be seen.

Thanks in advance.
Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

beans should be defined this way:

```
@ManagedBean(name="treeBean")
@SessionScoped // or whatever scope you would like to use
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {
....
```

Usage in XHTML: `...="#{treeBean.root}"`

**Or**

```
@ManagedBean(name="xyz")
@SessionScoped // or whatever scope you would like to use
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {
....
```

Usage in XHTML: `...="#{xyz.root}"`

bean name is just a key for the map, you can name it whatever you want

the scope of the bean should be from the package `javax.faces.bean`

i.e. for **sessionscoped** beans you have to import

```
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
```

and for the managedBean Annotation

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
```

Comment: Thanks Rami. I had used the wrong import - I think I took my eye off the ball when eclipse tried to help me fix it.

Comment: Welcome, glad that I could help

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/) you can find different ways to define a JSF managed bean and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986847/java-ee-6-javax-annotation-managedbean-vs-javax-inject-named-vs-javax-faces) you can find a really good discuss about managed beans.